# How to add Properties to an Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I have a Standalone Application, this application calculates a value (Property) and then starts a Spring Context.
My question is how can I add that calculated property to the spring context, so that I can use it like properties loaded from a property file (`@Value("${myCalculatedProperty}")`)?

To illustrate it a bit

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String myCalculatedProperty = magicFunction();         
    AbstractApplicationContext appContext =
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    //How to add myCalculatedProperty to appContext (before starting the context)

    appContext.getBean(Process.class).start();
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:*.properties" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.app"/>
```

It is a Spring 3.0 Application.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Spring 3.1 you can implement your own `PropertySource`, see: [Spring 3.1 M1: Unified Property Management](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/).

First, create your own `PropertySource` implementation:

```
private static class CustomPropertySource extends PropertySource<String> {

    public CustomPropertySource() {super("custom");}

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String name) {
        if (name.equals("myCalculatedProperty")) {
            return magicFunction();  //you might cache it at will
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now add this `PropertySource` before refreshing the application context:

```
AbstractApplicationContext appContext =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"}, false
    );
appContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(
   new CustomPropertySource()
);
appContext.refresh();
```

From now on you can reference your new property in Spring:

```
<context:property-placeholder/>

<bean class="com.example.Process">
    <constructor-arg value="${myCalculatedProperty}"/>
</bean>
```

Also works with annotations (remember to add `<context:annotation-config/>`):

```
@Value("${myCalculatedProperty}")
private String magic;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Magic: " + magic);
}
```

Comment: @Ralph: no, unfortunately. Just for the record I added full `PropertySource` example implementation.

Comment: This actually works but you have to make sure you are using a version of Spring (including all dependencies) later than 3.0, otherwise you won't get very far.   Especially check the inclusions at the top of your context.xml file.

Comment: Can any one suggest me solution for spring-boot.

Comment: @PratikShah Since spring 3.1, you may add `@PropertySource("classpath:path/to/classpath/application.properties")` to a class with `@Configuration`. Plural `@PropertiySources` if you are on Java <= 7.x

Answer (score 8):

You can add the calculated value to the system properties:

```
System.setProperty("placeHolderName", myCalculatedProperty);
```

Comment: But be aware that this way You disable the possibility to override this property easily from outside of your app using startup parameters (i.e. -DplaceHolderName=someEnvSpecificValue). I think the possibility to use system properties was added to handle enviorment specific values and there are other possibilities to add Your custom properties into the context, i.e. registering more than one `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are controlling the creation of `ApplicationContext` as in your example, you can always add a `BeanRegistryPostProcessor` to add a second `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` into the context. It should have `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true"` and `order="1"` and resolve only the custom calculated properties using the `Properties` object. All other properties should be resolved by the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` from the XML that should have `order="2"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myCalculatedProperty` must be contained within one of your properties file (which are injected by the Spring `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer`).

EDIT : simply use the setter, something like this

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String myCalculatedProperty = magicFunction();         
    AbstractApplicationContext appContext =
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    Process p = appContext.getBean(Process.class);
    p.setMyCalculatedProperty(myCalculatedProperty);
    p.start();
}
```

Comment: This will work, but I do not want to create a property file (the value is not the same for each run of the application), I want to "inject" them directly.

Comment: Just use the setter of your property, no ?

Comment: I do not understand the last comment. The property within the spring context is used like a normal property (with @Value). I need to declare it somehow in the spring context, so that spring (PropertyPlaceholder) can use it like a property loaded from a property file.

Comment: I see, but this does not solve the problem. When I do so, I will need to search for all the fields annotated with `@Value` (and some of them are constructor parameter). So in the end this would make spring obsolete.