# How to provide custom logic to search for bean if it cannot be found in Spring Context

Tags: spring, javabeans

If the Spring context cannot find a bean referred to from my xml I want to be able to provide some custom logic (ie look in another Spring Context or create the bean programmatically) before a BeanNotFoundException (whatever the expection is) is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://dimafeng.com/2015/11/27/dynamic-bean-definition/) to define your beans dynamically (click on the link for an explanation).

Alternatively if you want to act on your bean in a lazy manner (instead of at app startup), which I strongly recommend not to do since you will have bugs related to the state of you beans config that is not visible at compile time: Anyway, you can surely add to your ApplicationContext a custom singleton : instead of calling getBean() from spring, if nothing was found, your class will be called to respond which bean corresponds to a bean name, and you will indirectly have the opportunity to handle BeanNotFoundException

See a post about the second (not recommended) solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294187/how-to-add-properties-to-an-application-context) : [How to add Properties to an Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294187/how-to-add-properties-to-an-application-context)

Comment: You're welcome @rascal1981, I don't recommend having an AppContext state that is different on each runtime (depending on whether a BeanNotFoundException was cought, and therefore a bean dynamically added or not): you will have to deal with very complex bugs where you will wonder if the bean was present in the conf at the moment the bug occurs or not. This will make the code not readable and all combinations of situations uncoverable. It may look nice on paper, but I think you should adopt a solution like this only if it's really necessary